# How big does a rectangle have to be so that while rotating it, another smaller rectangle behind it is never visible?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

Imagine I'm drawing a rectangle (`rectSmall`) of the size 1280x720.

This rectangle is static and never changes its position, size, rotation, etc.

Now I want to draw another, bigger rectangle on top of it (`rectBig`) that is continuously rotating around its center.

If `rectBig` has the same size as `rectSmall`, `rectSmall` will naturally be partly visible behind `rectBig` while `rectBig` is rotating (unless `rectBig`'s rotation angle is 0 or 360).

My question is: How big does `rectBig` have to be so that `rectSmall` is never visible behind `rectBig`?

(Sorry for my English :D)

Comment: Where is the centre of each rectangle? Is the big rectangle rotating about "its [own] centre" or "[the small rectangle's] centre"?

Comment: rotating around its own center

Comment: and the rectangles have the same center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal of `rectSmall` must be the minimal side length of `rectBig`.

Comment: @user377314: That is nice to hear :o)

Answer (score -1):

If the big rectangle has same centre as small rectangle,then big rectangle with minimum area to completely cover(during rotation) the small rectangle will be a square. The length of side of this square is the diameter of circle circumscribing the smaller rectangle. If you draw it, it would be clearer to you.